# Simple Javascript Joyride plugin in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I'm afraid my plugin isn't working properly because of a misunderstanding of rails. I'm adding [zurbs joyride plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin) to an index page.

I have the following in `vendor/assets/javascripts/joyride` -

```
joyride-2.0.3.js
jquery.cookie.js
modernizr.mq.js
```

And referencing them the following way in `application.js` -

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require joyride/joyride-2.0.3
//= require joyride/modernizr.mq.js
//= require joyride/jquery.cookie
//= require_tree .
```

And the appropriate css in `vendor/assets/stylesheets` -

```
joyride-2.0.3.css
```

And Referenced in `application.css` -

```
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require joyride-2.0.3
```

Now in my index view-

```
<h1 id="pageTitle">Title of the page</h1>

<ol id="list_index_tour">
 <li data-id="pageTitle">Here is where the title of your page goes!</li>
</ol>

<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
    $("#list_index_tour").joyride({
    });
  });
</script>
```

The tour is not initiated, instead I have an ordered list displayed. There is an application layout. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make a manifest file for this plugin. Create an `index.js` inside your subfolder and reference your assets.

In your application.js you can have just:

`//= require joyride`

You can also try to drop the `.js` part in `//= require joyride/modernizr.mq.js`

Comment: So, I could just have `joyride` folder under `vendor/assets/javascripts/joyride` with the joyride js files and reference it in the `application.js` ? This may seem like better organization but I don't see functionally how this would help my problem of not being able to initiate joyride. Unless, how I have it above is incorrect?

Comment: It's not incorrect, you will create an `index.js` inside your subfolder and require your subfolder name in `application.js`. It's a suggestion, to see if your problem is solved this way.

Comment: I see I'll give this a shot, but still curious why my intended solution didn't work. May not be on the rails side

Comment: The javascript console says something?

Comment: Nothing I could gather from the console. I got it kinda working by moving the script that calls joyride out of the index view into the application layout.

Answer (score 1):

Tmacram,

I answered a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202699/cannot-get-joyride-to-work-it-displays-a-list/18159506#18159506)

The original answer was correct about better organization of included files within Rails, but that wasn't causing your issue. The real reason this wasn't working is that Zurb's own instructions for setup are misleading. They say you can use whatever ID you want for your `<ol>` list that holds the steps of your guided tour, but you actually can't out of the box.

**Zurb's code for joyride is dependent upon a specific ID between the CSS/Javascript.** This ID and the relevant code is located within the included joyride.css file. The ID used there is "joyRideTipContent." I've pasted the relevant couple lines of code from the joyride.css file (they're near the very top):

```
#joyRideTipContent { display: none; }
.joyRideTipContent { display: none; }
```

If you would prefer to use a different ID, simply change the above code in the css file as follows and then it will work (I've included the name from your code snippet above):

```
#list_index_tour{ display: none; }
.list_index_tour{ display: none; }
```

**Alternatively, you could just change the ID and selector of your `<ol>` to be "joyRideTipContent" and it would work right out of the box.**

Answer (score 0):

i have been having the same issue with joyride, i just got it working  , just to complete what already said in my case

first step : in the vendor/assets/javascripts i remove the js at the end of the file name and also in the application.js  place the require file in the same order from the demo. and also require the css file

second step : i create a partial that contain the code for the joyride place it in the folder that will contain the joyride views and render it in the layout/application.html.erb place after my footer

3rd step: i convert the javascript in coffeescript with js2coffee.org
  exemple from the demo

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
      autoStart : true,
      postStepCallback : function (index, tip) {
      if (index == 2) {
        $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
      }
    },
    modal:true,
    expose: true
    });
  });
```

to coffeescript:

```
 $(window).load ->
  $("#joyRideTipContent").joyride
    autoStart: true
    postStepCallback: (index, tip) ->
      $(this).joyride "set_li", false, 1  if index is 2

    modal: true
    expose: true
```

so basically this is the step that i did and it works for me .

P.s try not to put the file in another folder inside vendor/assets/javascripts , they are going to be compiled anyway.